# The verb for when someone's "autonomy" is violated

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

> They are going to make the decision without telling him. I think they
>   are ---- his autonomy.

What verb to use for the above sentence? Violate? Deprive him from? Harm? ...

Answer (score 2):

***[Violate](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/violate)***

to treat irreverently or disrespectfully; desecrate; profane; fail to respect (someone's peace, privacy, or rights)

***[Violate autonomy](http://bioethicsdiscussion.blogspot.com/2009/11/violation-of-patients-autonomy-is-that.html)***

**Physicians have to be careful not to violate a patient's autonomy by performing procedures not agreed to by the patient.**

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can take this.

> violate (verb): treat (something sacred) with irreverence or disrespect.
>
> - break or fail to comply with (a rule or formal agreement).

This has a more personal connotation.

> disregard (verb): pay no attention to; ignore.

This has a colder connotation

> infringe (verb): act so as to limit or undermine (something); encroach on.

This can be perceived as a sort of middle ground between the two. You should use a word appropriate to the relationship between the speaker and the person whose autonomy is being infringed upon.

Answer (score -1):

thwart

This is used particularly in the self-determination/psychological sense of autonomy.

Autonomy can be supported. It can also be thwarted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).